# In Excel, is there a way to determine the method being called by a password protected 3rd-party ribbon button?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I'm looking to automate a simple process in VBA and need to "click" a ribbon button.  It makes the most sense to just call the button's underlying method.  Is there a way to figure out what it is?

We are using Excel 2007 and 2010.

Comment: Just to clarify, since it's 2007/10, is the button on the ribbon?  If so, and since it's a 3rd party button, I'm not sure how to find its attributes, but I'll give it a try.  If, by chance, the button is on a right-click context menu or in the Addins tab, then the Excel 2003 method I proposed in my answer would work.  Details about the exact button location would be great.  (FYI, "toolbar" indicates the pre-Ribbon/pre-Excel 2007 menu system.)

Comment: I've looked into this some more and the answer seems to be that it's not possible to execute - or access - a 3rd party button on the ribbon.  You can execute built-in ribbon controls with the Commandbars.ExecuteMso method, but not custom ones.

Comment: Doug, thanks for the tenacity on this one.  I updated the question to reflect 'ribbon' instead of 'toolbar'.

Answer (score 2):

If it's Excel 2003 or earlier, you can use the CommandbarControl.Execute method.  For instance:

```
Application.Commandbars("3rd Party Toolbar").Controls("Button to Push").Execute
```

Comment: I think this is the opposite of what he is looking for.  From his question I think he wishes to find out what Macro is being called by the button.

Comment: @Toby.  He says he needs to click the button, and supposes the easiest way to do that is find the underlying macro.  I would say the easiest way is to just click it, which is what I showed him how to do.

Comment: @Doug: Good point, but you should state this in the answer, otherwise it'll be a -1 magnet.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways you can do this.

1. Right click on the toolbar and select Customise.  If you right click on the button there may be details somewhere of what Macro the button is associated with.
2. If you record a macro and click the button.  Then you can look at the VBA workspace and view the code that is generated to run your macro (which is just clicking the button you want).  This will show you what method the macro clicks.

Comment: Does this address the "3rd Party" aspect that's in the OP title?  Number 2 won't help with that, and #1 won't if the VBA is password-protected, which I assume it is, otherwise he could just look at the code.  For example, it won't work with the Adobe PDF menu.